# Accessing a specific indexes in an array C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

Hey guys so I wish to access an array in a sequential order

```
int get_value_from_array(char* buffer, int byte1, int byte2) {
    int i;
    int *j;
    j = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *j= 0;

    for(i = 0; i < byte2 - byte1; i++) {
        *j += (buffer[byte1+i] << (i*8));       
    }

    return j;
}
```

I wish to get some value from point1 to point2 starting from point1. Each is 8 bytes so I shifted by 8. And I'm adding it to `j` and returning it with `j`. The way I got this array is by using `mmap` and reading off some `fat.dat` file. First of all, I am getting really wild values... I don't understand. I dereferenced `j` by setting its value as 0 and adding the values to `j` afterwards.

I have also been following this [example](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/). I am not allowed to use `malloc` to solve this question but then I am even more confused. I tried to use this without the pointers but then I would get floating point exception.

Can you please help me how to fix this?

==========EDIT=====================
ok maybe my question was not clear enough =[

```
int get_value_from_array(char* buffer, int byte1, int byte2) {
    int i;
    int j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < byte2 - byte1; i++) {
        j += (buffer[byte1+i] << (i*8));        
    }

    return j;
}
```

this was my first attempt to get this thing working but I kept getting floating point exception. I searched up some stuff and found that an alternative way to do this is casting the value into a pointer and dereferenccing it. I've made some attempts but it's not working so great (or at least returning the most random value + sometimes a seg fault). I hope this clarifies what I wish to do.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, but `malloc(sizeof(int))` doesn't look like it's enough space.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for buffer, byte 1, byte 2, and your expected j?  Also, j is a pointer to an int, do you want to be returning the value of j perhaps?  For that matter, why are you dynamically allocating j?

Comment: @iharob tbh I've just followed the example on the link.

Comment: @dsolimano so the bytes(byte1, byte2) are merely an integer to indicate where from and to in the array I wish to access. each array holds 2 hex for example, AA, 0E, etc. So basically If i have 00 02, I would be reading this in little endian and want returned value of 512. (since 00 02 would be 0200 and 2*16^2 = 512). However if I have 02 02 00 then I would want decimal form of 00 02 02 and yeah!

Comment: @jonathanLeffler refer to my comment =] thank you!

Comment: `j` is a pointer to an `int`. You've said your function returns an `int`, but then it returns `j`. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm going to remove my previous comment.  You don't need to allocate `j`; indeed, you are wasting space if you do on a 64-bit machine (not that space actually matters), but you are also leaking space because you don't free `j`, and that matters.  You can't (as in "shouldn't, and you must be ignoring compiler warnings if you think your code compiles") return `j` from a function returning `int`.  You either need to return an `int *` (but why would you want to), or you need to return `*j`, but that leaves you with an unsolveable leak.  Define `int j = 0;` and don't allocate memory.

Comment: Make `buffer` an unsigned char *, or cast `buffer[byte1+i]` to unsigned char, otherwse you will get negative bytes.  And do what Jonathan Leffler said, don't malloc and just make `j` a plain int.

Comment: @davidSchwartz sry =[ I tried my best to get this code at least working and that was what I have.

Comment: But your code is not compiling cleanly.  Your compiler is telling you there are mistakes because it complains about you returning an `int *` from a function that is supposed to return an `int`.  You can't afford to ignore your compiler's warnings; it knows more about C than you do at this stage in your C programming career.  (If your compiler isn't giving you such warnings, you must be using an archaic compiler and should upgrade to something written in the last quarter century.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your kind help, I've made some edit in my question. Would you please look at it please? Thank you!

Comment: @HyunwooLim edit that example into the question, it'll make it easier for others to respond I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what you're after.

```
int get_value_from_array(char* buffer, int byte1, int byte2)
{
    int j = 0;
    assert(buffer != 0);
    assert(byte1 >= 0 && byte2 >= byte1 && (size_t)(byte2 - byte1) < sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < byte2 - byte1; i++)
        j += (unsigned char)buffer[byte1+i] << (i*8);

    return j;
}
```

As noted in my comment, you really don't want to allocate `int *j` for multiple reasons, including "you aren't allowed to use `malloc()`" and "it leaks memory when misused as in your question".

---

And, honest, I wrote this code before I saw your update to the question!
The `assert()` and `(unsigned char)` cast are the only differences between your original code and this code.  I'm not sure how you get a floating point exception out of that.  You can get one of those if you divide by zero, but there isn't an obvious division in your code, let alone division by zero.

You should go back to your original code and print all the information out as it runs.  Or use a debugger to step through it.

```
int get_value_from_array(char* buffer, int byte1, int byte2)
{
    int j = 0;
    printf("-->> %s: %p (%d..%d)\n", __func__, buffer, byte1, byte2);
    assert(buffer != 0);
    assert(byte1 >= 0 && byte2 >= byte1 && (size_t)(byte2 - byte1) < sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < byte2 - byte1; i++)
    {
        printf("j0 = 0x%.8X, i = %d, byte = 0x%.2X, "
               "add = 0x%.8X, j1 = 0x%.8X\n",
               j, i, (unsigned char)buffer[byte1+i],
               (unsigned char)buffer[byte1+i] << (i*8),
               j + (unsigned char)buffer[byte1+i] << (i*8));
        j += (unsigned char)buffer[byte1+i] << (i*8);
    }

    printf("<<-- %s: 0x%.8X\n", __func__, j);
    return j;
}
```

Note that printing ends with a newline.  In C99, `__func__` is the name of the function; omit if you have C89/C90, and remove the `%s` — or replace `%s` with your function name (or replace `__func__` with your function name as a string literal: `"get_value_from_array"`).

Debuggable code written in C89/C90:

```
int get_value_from_array(char* buffer, int byte1, int byte2)
{
    static const char func[] = "get_value_from_array";
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    printf("-->> %s: %p (%d..%d)\n", func, buffer, byte1, byte2);
    assert(buffer != 0);
    assert(byte1 >= 0 && byte2 >= byte1 && (size_t)(byte2 - byte1) < sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < byte2 - byte1; i++)
    {
        printf("j0 = 0x%.8X, i = %d, byte = 0x%.2X, "
               "add = 0x%.8X, j1 = 0x%.8X\n",
               j, i, (unsigned char)buffer[byte1+i],
               (unsigned char)buffer[byte1+i] << (i*8),
               j + (unsigned char)buffer[byte1+i] << (i*8));
        j += (unsigned char)buffer[byte1+i] << (i*8);
    }

    printf("<<-- %s: 0x%.8X\n", func, j);
    return j;
}
```

Comment: (loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode)
this is the reason why I have int i declared outside of the for loop. as for assert, it does not recognize the function. and I am still getting floating point exception as I have noted in the editted question.

Comment: OK; time to get a better compiler (one which support the 15 year old standard or even the 4 year old standard, rather than the 25 year old one).  OK; if you're stuck with what Microsoft gives you, I'm sorry for you.  You will have to make some minor changes to the debug code too.  Or specify C99 mode (`-std=c99`, or better to use `-std=c11` if you're using GCC, which you might be given that message; you should be learning modern C, not the archaic stuff).  If you are using GCC or clang, compile with `-Wall -Werror` at minimum; preferably add `-Wextra` too.

Comment: I am not allowed to change my compiler =[  and this is the output of your [debug](http://i.imgur.com/Fiwqq4o.png). 11 and 12 hold hex values of 00 02 respectively, but on your debug j is still 0 =[. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The code only goes once through the loop because 12 - 11 is 1.  So you either need to call the function with `11, 13` or change the loop condition to `i <= byte2 - byte1 + 1`.  Since your array contains 0x00 0x02, you are getting the correct result for what you wrote, but what you wrote wasn't quite what you intended.  Are you sure your FPE was from this code, or could it have come later in the program?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think he wants byte2 included in the value.  So just change the `<` to a `<=`.

Comment: ok guys i've just made the worst dick move ever... yeah that was it. that was causing the stupid floating point exception thank you all so much for helping me out =]

Comment: @HyunwooLim: the most important thing is that you learned, I hope, how to debug such problems.  I like and use printing a lot; other people infinitely prefer a debugger.  Both mechanisms work.  Make sure you know how to use at least one of the techniques, preferably both.